# All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica

Tags: vb.net, itext

I want to create a PDF/A-1A File with iText, but I can not get around the classical Helvetica Error, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.
Here's the code:

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim document As Document = New Document(PageSize.A4)
    Dim writer As PdfAWriter = PdfAWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream("./Test.pdf", FileMode.Create), PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A)

    writer.CreateXmpMetadata()
    document.Open()
    'The sRGB File is located in my Resources.'
    Dim icc = ICC_Profile.GetInstance(My.Resources.sRGB)
    writer.SetOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc)


    Dim fonts As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("./FreeSansBold.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 10)
    Dim normal9 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("./FreeSans.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 9)
    Dim bold9 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("./FreeSansBold.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 9)
    Dim normal8 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("./FreeSans.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 8)


    document.Add(New Paragraph("Hello world"))

    writer.Close()
    document.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

If you have questions, just ask me. I hope you can help me.

Regards

Nadix.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is what you already know, all fonts must be embedded, even the "core PDF fonts".

The longer answer is that iText isn't a PDF renderer and as such doesn't have a need for the core PDF fonts, at least not completely. Per the standard, all conforming renderers must have these fonts (or appropriate substitutions) available so there's no reason for iText to include them. (Not to mention any potential licensing issues.) It does ship with the AFM files which holds font metrics but that's just for figuring out how to lay text out.

The solution is to always declare, embed and use your own fonts. You can buy a license for embedded Helvetica and use that if you want, too. There currently is no way to set a document-wide default font so you either need to always specify the font or come up with a wrapper. One way would be to just have a helper method:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ''//Register our font
    FontFactory.Register(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF"), "Arial Unicode MS")
End Sub
Public Shared Function CreateParagraph(text As String) As Paragraph
    Static ArialUnicode = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Unicode MS", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 20)
    Return New Paragraph(text, ArialUnicode)
End Function
```

Another way would be to subclass `Paragraph`

```
Public Class ParagraphArial
    Inherits iTextSharp.text.Paragraph
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property ThisFont As Font
        Get
            Return FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Unicode MS", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 20)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New(text As String)
        MyBase.New(text, ThisFont)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Both would be used like this:

```
document.Add(CreateParagraph("Hello world"))
document.Add(New ParagraphArial("Second Test"))
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and explain or send me the whole code per e-mail?

Comment: I don't know what more you need. If you want PDF/A-1A compliance than you basically need to always use `New Paragraph()` with a font that you've previously embedded. By itself, `document.Add(New Paragraph("Hello world"))` uses the system default which is not embedded.

Comment: Okay, i got everything in place now and it is working. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @Nadix could you take a look at the question here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736441/3169868